# How do I export an array with module.exports in node js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have a project using node.js. It's my first time using nodejs and I want to export an array to my app. Here is some code:

```
module.exports = { 
    var arrays = [];
    arrays[0] = 'array 0';
    arrays[1] = 'array 1';
    arrays[2] = 'array 2';
    arrays[3] = 'array 3';
    arrays[4] = 'array 4';
    var r_array = arrays[Math.floor(Math.random() * arrays.length)].toString();
}
```

At the end I want to use the `var r_array` in my app.js but I don't know how.

Comment: Please, use Arrays the proper / simpler way: `const arrays = ["a", "b", /*etc*/ ];`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You'd want to define a function which returns the randomized portion of the array:

```
module.exports = {
  getRArray: function() {
    var arrays = [];
    arrays[0] = 'array 0';
    arrays[1] = 'array 1';
    arrays[2] = 'array 2';
    arrays[3] = 'array 3';
    arrays[4] = 'array 4';
    return arrays[Math.floor(Math.random()*arrays.length)];
  }
};
```

Also you should embed the array into the function so it actually returns something.

Answer (score 5):

`module.exports` needs to be an object.

Perhaps you're looking for something more like:

```
var arrays = [];
arrays[0] = 'array 0';
arrays[1] = 'array 1';
arrays[2] = 'array 2';
arrays[3] = 'array 3';
arrays[4] = 'array 4';
var r_array = arrays[Math.floor(Math.random()*arrays.length)].toString();

module.exports = r_array;
```

Please note that this code will only be run once, and that if you're hoping to get a different random value by executing the code multiple times, that you may want to set it up more like:

```
module.exports = function() {
  return arrays[Math.floor(Math.random()*arrays.length)];
}
```

so that the `Math.random()` operation happens over and over.

Comment: module.exports can export an array directly. It does not need to be an object. (Though, it is true that an array is a type of an object)

Answer (score 0):

```
var arrays = [];
arrays[0] = 'array 0';
arrays[1] = 'array 1';
arrays[2] = 'array 2';
arrays[3] = 'array 3';
arrays[4] = 'array 4';
var r_array = arrays[Math.floor(Math.random()*arrays.length)].toString();
module.exports = r_array;
```

Comment: okay thank you! but i have an additional question. then there is only one random array. how do i have to do it if i want every time another array? :)

Comment: You should check @therobinkim answer. But note that you are not going to get a random array every time if you are applying `toString` to the result. This means the value will be translated into a string, so you'll get a random string every time.

Answer (score 0):

You have two files, one is array.js and the other app.js.
Consider doing this in **array.js** file:

```js
const Array= [
    'array 0',
    'array 1',
    'array 2',
    'array 3',
    'array 4']
   
exports.Array = Array
```

Now in your **app.js** do the following:

```js
const { Array } = require("./array")

const randomArr = Array[Math.floor(Math.random()*Array.length)]
console.log(randomArr)
 // I used randomArr  instead of r_array because of JS conventions.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this , if you are using type : "module" in package.json

```js
const myArray = [
       {
            name: 'Cake',
            value: 'cake'
        },
        {
            name: 'Veg thali',
            value: 'vegthali'
        }
]

export default myArray
```

```js
import myArray from "./arrayfile.js"
```